# Find element and send keys with Selenium python (blogspot comments)

Tags: python, selenium

I wanna make a comment in a blogspot with Selenium, chromedriver and python.

I tried everything but i can't find the correct XPATH to the comment textarea:
https://testeblogger6.blogspot.com/2020/04/comment.html

Its appears that the Google comment box is a different frame.
I tried:

```
textarea=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="commentBodyField"]')
```

and also

```
textarea=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/textarea')
```

But Always it results: "no such element: Unable to locate element"

Please, someone give me the correct xpath or ID for the comment textarea of this blog, to send keys!

Comment: I tried to find the frame ID or xpath also, but I couldn't

Answer (score 0):

Based on what i have saw you have to execute:

- first click on the element
- then send the text

text area can be located by id: commentBodyField

```
textarea = driver.find_element_by_id('commentBodyField')
textarea.click()
textarea.clear()
textarea.send_keys(text)
```

if the click fails for the text area try to click on the wrapper

```
textareawrap = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.commentBodyContainer')
textareawrap.click()
<send text method after that>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
driver.get('https://testeblogger6.blogspot.com/2020/04/comment.html')
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
      EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'comment-editor')))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)


element=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'commentBody')))

actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
actionChains.move_to_element(element).send_keys("aaaaa").perform()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**Output:**

[image]